# How to join a Ubuntu desktop client to a ubuntu server domain controller

Tags: 14.04, samba, active-directory, domain-server, samba4

What I want to do is to authenticate ubuntu users across the network. I have already created the domain, what I need to know is how to log in the users, save their personal settings and stuff like that. I am portuguese so I'm sorry if I commit any grammatical or writing mistake.

I have tried to google how to do this but everything that I found was how to join a ubuntu client to a windows server domain and that's not what I want.

This is very important, please help me!!!

Comment: Linux does not work like that. Could you please be more specific? Like what would you like to achieve by this? What is the purpose of this? File-sharing, permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

I made a comment for you to rephrase your question. But I'm quite sure the answer you are looking for is not an easy fix. Therefore i would recommend you read this tutorial about Linux and Active Directory. I'm sure you will find your answer. (Or what to ask).

This is a guide to Active Directory on linux:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.12.linux.aspx

Comment: You must detail what's in the link in your answer in case the link dies

Comment: Is this what you ment?

Comment: No, I want to authenticate ubuntu users into a ubuntu server domain controller.